# Next.js - styling for 2 languages

Tags: next.js, sass, next-intl

I have 2 languages in 1 site, English and Arabic, and the only difference in terms of styling between these 2 sites is that for example, the padding-left becomes padding-right, same thing applies for margins and positions, so I am trying to avoid any CSS duplication and I thought to myself that i should create some sorts of variables in my SCSS modules, has anyone ever encountered this issue? I didn't find any resources that tackle this issue (The language thingy is being handled by next-intl, I am using next.js and  scss modules for my styling).

I am using scss modules and as usual each component has its own scss.module files.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags. You could improve your earlier questions, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS provides built-in support for [Logical Properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_logical_properties_and_values). This feature simplifies styling by allowing you to define properties once, with the browser automatically adjusting them based on the parent's `dir` attribute.

For instance, instead of specifying `padding-left: 1rem`, you should opt for `padding-inline-start: 1rem`.

### Syntax:

```css
[property]-[axis]-[direction]: [value]
```

- The axis can be either `inline` or `block`.
- The direction can be `start` or `end`.
  The supported properties include:
- padding
- margin
- inset (top, left, bottom, right)
- text-align
- border
- border-radius
- scroll-padding
- scroll-margin

To utilize logical properties, set the parent's page direction (or the `html` tag) as follows:

```html
// This is a JSX code
<html dir={lang === "ar" ? "rtl" : "ltr"}>
```

Subsequently, employ logical properties instead of physical ones. For example:

| Don't | Do |
| --- | --- |
| `padding-left` | `padding-inline-start` |
| `padding-right` | `padding-inline-end` |
| `padding-top` | `padding-block-start` |
| `padding-bottom` | `padding-block-end` |
| `margin-left` | `margin-inline-start` |
| `margin-right` | `margin-inline-end` |
| `border-left` | `border-inline-start` |
| `border-right` | `border-inline-end` |
| `border-top-left-radius` | `border-start-start-radius`, `border-start-end-radius`, `border-end-start-radius`, `border-end-end-radius` |
| `text-align: left` | `text-align: start` |
| `scroll-padding-left` | `scroll-padding-inline-start` |
| `scroll-padding-right` | `scroll-padding-inline-end` |
| `scroll-margin-left` | `scroll-margin-inline-start` |
| `scroll-margin-right` | `scroll-margin-inline-end` |

By doing this, `padding-inline-start` functions as `padding-left` in LTR languages and as `padding-right` in RTL languages. For top-to-down languages like Japanese, use `padding-block-start` instead of `padding-top`.

If you're working with tailwindcss, I've developed [eslint plugin](https://github.com/a7med3bdulbaset/eslint-plugin-rtl-friendly) that warns if you write physical property class and suggest you use its logical equivalent. I don't know if there is a similar [styleLint](https://stylelint.io/) plugin for CSS and SCSS.